# Mapillary depth dataset - am I misunderstanding what depthmaps are?

Tags: depth, mapillary

Mapillary has published a few months ago a [dataset of street view pictures along with, according to the website, depth information](https://www.mapillary.com/dataset/depth): "The dataset is generated by running monocular Structure-from-Motion and multi-view stereo to obtain dense depth for eligible images."

What I was expecting to see was a picture where each pixel of the street view image is transformed into a gray-scaled pixel, depending on how far the source pixel is from the camera, as explained in the ["depth map" Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_map).

However, when browsing the dataset, the depthmaps don't seem to represent depth at all: the objects on the source image have a similar shade of gray whether they're at 5 or 20 meters from the camera, and close objects (like the street in the example hereunder) don't show at all.

Is the depth map inaccurate or am I msunderstanding what it's supposed to represent?

Source image:
[image]

Corresponding depth map, according to Mapillary:
[image]